# Mod-Rewrite - using mixed url structure

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a requirement to rewrite an URL, but not with an exact order.

For example, I need to be able to have:

```
www.domain.com/sale
www.domain.com/sale/new-york
www.domain.com/sale/offices
www.domain.com/sale/chicago/villas
www.domain.com/new-york
www.domain.com/washington/offices
```

and so on. In the end, it will have to go to something like:

```
file.php?type=sale
file.php?type=sale&city=new-york
file.php?type=sale&category=offices
file.php?type=sale&city=chicago&category=villas
file.php?city=new-york
file.php?city=washington&category=offices
```

So the main idea is that I will not have a specific order of subfolders, which I could use to build a generic rule.

The only solution to this problem I found to be a .htaccess automatically generated which includes all possible cases and variations of requests (assuming that a category name will never be the same with a city name and/or a type).

Is there any other possibility to achieve this with a regular expression?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### I propose you to test this in /.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule \b(sale)\b /file.php?%{QUERY_STRING}&type=$1
RewriteRule \b(chigaco|new-york|washington)\b /file.php?%{QUERY_STRING}&city=$1
RewriteRule \b(villas|offices)\b /file.php?%{QUERY_STRING}&category=$1
```

We use:

```
\bsale\b: sale is a whole word delimited by word boundary.
\b(chigaco|new-york|washington)\b: cities names must be known.
\b(villas|offices)\b: category names must be predictable.
```

I've tested with this /file.php:

```
This is file.php
<?php
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($_GET);
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

It rewrites http://www.example.com/sale/new-york/villas as this, file.php outputs this content:

```
This is file.php
array(3) {
  ["type"]=>
  string(4) "sale"
  ["city"]=>
  string(8) "new-york"
  ["category"]=>
  string(6) "villas"
}
```

#### If you have all World cities to be handled, a trade-off must be done, cities be prefixed as this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule \b(sale)\b /file.php?%{QUERY_STRING}&type=$1
RewriteRule \b(villas|offices)\b /file.php?%{QUERY_STRING}&category=$1
RewriteRule \bcity-([\w-]+)\b /file.php?%{QUERY_STRING}&city=$1
```

Ie, you must use URL like this in your HTML documents:

```
http://www.example.com/sale/city-new-york/villas
http://www.example.com/sale/city-beijing/offices
http://www.example.com/sale/villas/city-berlin
```

Comment: From my first tests, it seems that this solution might work. Thanks. The only question that's coming for now is how many  characters I can use for a rule - for example how many cities can I add to \b(chigaco|new-york|washington)\b?

Comment: This may be very long, but not infinite.